# Two handed object rig issue

Tags: animation, rigging, constraints, parent, dynamic

Im trying to parent two hands to a broom handle.
I created one armature with 3 bones and parented it to the stick of the broom
Used the add-on Dynamic parent to attach the leading hand to the base bone
then proceeded to parent bone 3 to the other hand
Ive tried this also in reverse and even using Child-of constrain on the second hand making sure to set inverse
Every attempt ends  up wih a similar attemp as shown in the attachment with the hand separating from the handle as the animation progresses
I have ensured there are no previous keyframes on the second hand at the moment of contact but the result is the same.

I would appreciate any advise on the issue

Thank you

[image]